# What is the best way to implicitly assign an ID to a sequence of operations?

Tags: ruby

I have a sequence of operations (henceforth *sequence*) to be called, and I want to assign a unique ID to the seqnence and be able to call that ID from anywhere within the sequence without passing it as an argument throughout the sequence. Sequences may be nested, and when an operation is called within a sequence within another sequence, I would like to call the innermost one.

One way to do this is to use threads. If I perform the sequence of operations within a newly created thread, then the current thread would work as the ID:

```
Thread do
  ...
  id = Thread.current
  ...
end
```

But in my particular case, I cannot let a sequence correspond to a thread one-to-one, so I would like an alternative way to do this. What would be a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `Fiber` instead of `Thread`. I am doing it like this:

```
require "fiber"
Fiber.new do
  ...
  id = Fiber.current
  ...
end.resume
```